# Finding 3D velocity vector

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, physics

How do I find the 3D velocity vector? I have the the starting position, the ending position and the speed of the projectile.

Also, how do I find the velocity vector if the target is moving?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the object is travelling along a straight line, then get the direction vector (end position minus start position), normalize and scale by the speed.

Comment: You should elaborate on the second part, e.g. what exactly is Target, what information do we have about it.

Comment: Target has has all info like Location, Velocity and such

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the components of the positions are `x`, `y`, and `z`, then you can decompose the movement of the missile:

```
dx = endPosition.x - startPosition.x
dy = endPosition.y - startPosition.y
dz = endPosition.z - startPosition.z
```

You can find the total movement:

```
d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)
```

Then you can calculate the velocity vector:

```
vx = dx/d * missileSpeed
vy = dy/d * missileSpeed
vz = dz/d * missileSpeed
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the moving target? I have to find a tentative location of the Target and determine if the missile will hit the target. The Target is moving at it's own velocity and the projectile is shot a certain speed.

Comment: Use the same technique: calculate the target's motion in the x, y, and z directions.  You can calculate the target's position along an axis at time `t` as `x0 + t*vx` where `x0` is its start position on the axis, and `vx` is its speed along the axis.  Calculate its position along the x, y, and z axes; then do the same for the missile.  If both objects are in the same place at the same time, the missile hits the target.